# How to add days over month?

Tags: c#, datetime

i'm really happy with my Code but there is one problem left.

I have this Code (short version):

```
if (holidays.Contains(eskalation.Value.Date))
{
    eskalationsZeit = new DateTime(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month, eskalation.Value.Day + 1, 8, 0, 0);
    if (eskalation.Value.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month))
    {
        eskalation = new DateTime(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month + 1, 1, 8, 0, 0);

        if (eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
              eskalation = new DateTime(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month + 1, 3, 8, 0, 0);
              }
              else if (eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
              {
                  eskalation = new DateTime(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month + 1, 2, 8, 0, 0);
              }
        }
}
```

In this Code i'm asking if the Day is a holiday (List), or saturday or sunday and if it's the last day of the month so i have to change the month.
Everything is working fine BUT -

if i have the 28th of a month with 30 Days and it is a holiday i'll add 1 Day, so i've the 29th. Now the 29th is a saturday so i'll add another 2 Days but at this point i get my Exception because i add the Days like this:

```
if (eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    eskalation = new DateTime(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month, eskalation.Value.Day + 2, 8, 0, 0);
}
```

So the result would be the 31st Day of a Month with only 30 Days.

How can i add Days over a Month? Like - if the result of adding Days is greater than days in month - take the first (second, third or whatever) of the next month?! Is there a method or a fast solution for that?

Thanks for every help.

cheers Dave

Comment: Can't you do `eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(1);`?

Comment: What precisely are you trying to achieve? Give more info on what/why you are doing this?

Comment: It's a reporting app - i've to calculate escalation dates of sent tickets. Escalation date is never a holiday or on a weekend so i have to get the date from my DB and afterwards calculate if it's neither a holiday or a day on a weekend.

Comment: if it's on a holiday or on a weekend i've to add days till the next "working day" (monday - friday)

Comment: OK - now i know why i took the `new DateTime` - because i have to set the time too. It's not only `AddDays` - the new Day should start on 8am too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the [`AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method it will handle the change in both month and year automatically for you in the event that there is an overflow...

```
eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(numOfDays);
```

---

With that in mind, I believe the following code will do what you need:

```
// Keep looping until we find a date that we like
while(true)
{
    if(holidays.Contains(eskalation.Value.Date))
        eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(1);
    else if(eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(2);
    else if(eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(1);
    else
        break;
}
```

**NOTE**: You can tidy up the code with brackets, and improve the logic if you wish. I just wanted to keep it short to make it easier to understand what is happening

Comment: OK - now i know why i took the `new DateTime` - because i have to set the time too. It's not only `AddDays` - the new Day should start on 8am too.

Comment: @DaveS.: Just set the time as a one off at the very start then, before the loop

Comment: Did it in the return! Everything is fine and working brilliant!
Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(1);
```

It will handle instances where some months are longer than others for you. It's also a lot cleaner/easier than what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it simple

```
// isFreeDay can check for weekends, holidays, ...
while (isFreeDay(eskalation.Value.Date)) 
{
    eskalation = eskalation.Value.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this :

```
if (eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    eskalation = new DateTime(eskalation.Value.Year, eskalation.Value.Month, eskalation.Value.Day + 2, 8, 0, 0);
}
```

Just do this :

```
while (eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || eskalation.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    eskalation = eskalation.AddDays(1) ; 
}
```